# Count number of groups having a specific value over multiple variables

Tags: r, grouping

I have a data frame such as:

```
city <- c("a","a","b","b","c","c","c","c","d","e","e","f") 
x <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1)
y <- c(1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1)
z <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)
k <- c(1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0)
df <- data.frame(city, x, y, z, k)
```

where there is a grouping variable (e.g. city) and several dummy variables. I would like to count how many cities have each dummy variable = 1.

What I managed so far is to count how many cities have a specific dummy = 1:

```
> n_groups(filter(df, x == 1) %>% 
+            group_by(city))
[1] 4
```

However, I would like to know whether it is possible to do that for all the dummies in my data frame so to obtain something like:

```
var count 
 x   4
 y   4
 z   2
 k   3
```

in which I have the number of cities having each dummy variables equal 1 (the count column) without having to do it individually for all the dummies in my sample.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R base:

```
colSums(rowsum(df[, -1], df[, 1]) > 0)

#x y z k 
#4 4 2 3
```

Comment: didn't know about this function `rowsum()`!

Comment: I think this is a more simple solution among the others proposed here.

Comment: wrap `stack` around it and you get the expected output format

Answer (score 2):

With the `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  gather(k, v, -1) %>% 
  filter(v == 1) %>% 
  group_by(k) %>% 
  summarise(cnt = n_distinct(city))
```

The result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  k       cnt
  <chr> <int>
1 k         3
2 x         4
3 y         4
4 z         2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, lapply(.SD, max), city][, colSums(.SD), .SDcols = -1]
x y z k 
4 4 2 3
```